# equation with 2 ranges

Tags: equations

[image: how to write the range of variable for this example 1 equation has 2 range up and down with equation at centre]

i need to write the equation as n the figure attached plz someone help me out in writting the equattion with the ranges as in the example attached thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `array` environment:

```
\[
  u_i(a_1, x_2, x_3) - u_i(-a_1, x_2, x_3) = 2a_1\varepsilon_{i1}^0
  \qquad
  \begin{array}{c}
    -a_2 \leq x_2 \leq a_2 \\
    -a_3 \leq x_3 \leq a_3
  \end{array}
\]
```

Answer (score 1):

See, it this MWE gives what you like to achieve:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
u_i(a_1,x_2,x_3) - u_i(-a_1,x_2,x_3) = 2a_1\varepsilon_{i1}^0 
    &\quad  \begin{aligned}
                    -a_2\leq x_2 & \leq a_2\\
                    -a_2\leq x_2 & \leq a_2
            \end{aligned}   \\
u_i(a_1,x_2,x_3) - u_i(-a_1,x_2,x_3) = 2a_1\varepsilon_{i1}^0
    &\quad  \begin{aligned}
                    -a_2\leq x_2 & \leq a_2\\
                    -a_2\leq x_2 & \leq a_2
            \end{aligned}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why `\left`s and `\right`s only for the first u_i terms?

Comment: . ah, they are forgotten ... fro some other test, I will erase it.

Comment: There is an extra \ left in the first math line causing a `\)`. Can’t fix it myself because edits are permitted for at least 6 characters.